Flyback transformer inductance value variation
I have using core EE (E30/15/7-3C90-E100). In that I have winded 18turns - 2nd method (refer attachment) where inductance value observed 50uH higher than calculated (18x18x100x10^(-9)x1.05 = 34.02uH). 1.05 - Tolerance in AL Value of core.
Therefore, I have winded 1st method (Refer attachment) where inductance value observed closer to calculated value (18x18x100x10^(-9)x1.05 = 35.32uH) which was acceptable.
When winding in 2nd method, why inductance value observed higher?


50 μH higher? You're measuring about 2.5 times the calculated inductance?

What's the gap in the core, and is it consistent between the two scenarios? You don't need much change in gap to get a big change in inductance.

Hearth, No measured inductance observed higher as 1.4 times. But after changing winding structure to I pattern (Refer attachment) inductance value found ok.

John D, Gap is around 1100um and it is same for both patterns. And tell me how inductance values changes for both patterns.

Consider the field lines around the core:

Due to fringing field, turns near the center (I) are coupled less into the total core flux: effectively they see a smaller Ae (so the coupling factor for those turns is proportionate), thus have a smaller contribution to overall inductance.
Turns farther away (II), tend to couple more completely.  Notice that sharp boundaries tend to leak flux, not just the air gap itself but the inside corners will leak some as indicated.
The difference is nontrivial to calculate; some rough, hand-wave estimates of fringing field geometry can be made, and the Ae argument above applied (consider each turn, or group of turns in similar location, as windings of a nonideal transformer, wired in series), but it quickly gets preferable to just plug all these data into a field simulator and get a representative output directly.
The inhomogeneous field around the gap, also induces eddy currents in the wire; there is an argument to shape the bobbin such that windings are not placed in these poorly-coupled, high-eddy-current regions, optimizing for maximum inductivity (minimum turns required) and minimum losses as a result.  (Such bobbins can be 3D printed, and the exact dimensions calculated -- there used to be such a tool online in fact, but I don't remember where, and IIRC it's long since offline, sadly.)
Mostly, this isn't considered worthwhile, and the lower overall inductivity (AL) and Q are acceptable, or where the increased cost is worth the increased Q, litz wire is used.
Occasionally, you see a distributed air gap, in that rather than one lumped sum, floating pieces of ferrite are used to make smaller air gaps across the middle leg.  That is, the middle leg is cut into segments, each cut being gapped carefully.  This minimizes the fringe from each gap, making the field around the winding much more even, homogeneous, reducing eddy currents.
Occasionally as in, I've seen it more often these days, including offered as standard parts; but it's still a fairly fringe (hah) technique, I think?
A downside to this technique is, whereas the tolerance of a single gap might be, say, 0.5 ± 0.05 mm, the distributed gaps might be 4 x 0.1 ± 0.02 mm.  That's very tight.  Cores are ground by placing the spine on a table, and bringing a grinding wheel in over the upward-facing peg; if we minimize work by grinding just the middle peg to a specific height and tolerance, we introduce the error of the outer limbs' height and variation.  The total height (middle peg and limbs) might have to be ground first, or even made parallel (ends and spine face ground to tight tolerance), since the manufacture tolerances of both faces might not be sufficient.  Then the middle peg is ground to the difference required.  Finally, the resulting parts need to be measured to ensure they are within tolerance -- at least as a production sampling process.  This all takes more time, and hence increases cost of the assembly.
In a completely different direction, fringing field can be reduced (eliminated?) by removing bulk gaps entirely, using a "distributed air gap" material instead: powdered cores.  A metal (iron or alloy) powder is mixed with resin binder, pressed into a mold and bonded.  Typical shapes are toroids, with EE and other shapes used infrequently.  These have higher losses though: you can't avoid the higher hysteresis losses of the metal, even in the best alloys, and eddy currents tend to dominate at lower frequencies (100s kHz to low MHz).  Or they have much lower than ideal permeability (e.g. Micrometals #2) and copper losses dominate instead.  They are still quite suitable for switching inductors operating in CCM, and general purpose filtering applications.
